# How to open a link in a new tab when clicking on an image in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I made a simple Chrome Extension that, when clicked, has a dropdown menu that has a row of icons. Is it possible to set it so when the icon is clicked, it opens its respective website in a new tab?

(NOTE: I have tried to make it refer to a link in the `popup.html` file, but if I click on the icon, it doesn't do anything.)

Any help, suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This should help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: @smoggers This is not chrome extension specific

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a click handler to the icon that executes the following:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: websiteToOpen});
```

If you want it to open in the background without closing the popup, one more parameter is required:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: websiteToOpen, active: false});
```

Do note that `"tabs"` permission is *not* needed for this.

[This example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) from Chrome docs shows how to properly assign a click hanlder in a way that's compatible with Chrome extensions (`onclick` attribute will not work)

Answer (score 0):

@Xan
Hey, thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply... I figured it out though, and I didn't need to add any click handlers... I just did:

```
<a target = "_blank" href = "http://google.com">
  <img src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg"/>
</a>
```

the target attribute says to open it in a new tab and it does exactly that when I click on it. Problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: This works for most URLs, but not all. For instance, you can't open non-web URLs with it (`chrome://`, `chrome-extension://`, etc.) My solution is more robust and allows more customization.

Comment: Just a heads up to those using this solution in the future. This method is vulnerable to reverse tabnapping. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable/50709760 for a solution.